# How to define timeout for webservice client in websphere

Tags: web-services, timeout, websphere

Our application is hosted in websphere, my webservice client (jax-ws) is making webservice call to remote server. I will need to define timeout for this webservice call. I tried different way to set timeout up with no luck. here is what i tried:

```
    Map<String, Object> requestContext = ((BindingProvider) binding).getRequestContext();
    requestContext.put("com.ibm.websphere.webservices.jaxws.asynctimeout", 15000);
```

or

```
    Map<String, Object> requestContext = ((BindingProvider) binding).getRequestContext();
    requestContext.put(BindingProviderProperties.REQUEST_TIMEOUT, 15000);
    requestContext.put(BindingProviderProperties.CONNECT_TIMEOUT, 15000);
```

None of them works

Any one can give hint, how to setup timeout for webservice client in websphere?

Thx

Answer (score 0):

because Jax-WS in WAS relies on Axis 2 I believe you could use standard Axis 2 approach to do that, try(From axis 2 docs):

> Timeout Configuration

Two timeout instances exist in the transport level, Socket timeout and Connection timeout. These can be configured either at deployment or run time. If configuring at deployment time, the user has to add the following lines in axis2.xml.

For Socket timeout:

```
<parameter name="SO_TIMEOUT">some_integer_value</parameter>
For Connection timeout:

 <parameter name="CONNECTION_TIMEOUT">some_integer_value</parameter>
```

For runtime configuration, it can be set as follows within the client stub:
...

```
Options options = new Options();
options.setProperty(HTTPConstants.SO_TIMEOUT, new Integer(timeOutInMilliSeconds));
options.setProperty(HTTPConstants.CONNECTION_TIMEOUT, new Integer(timeOutInMilliSeconds));

// or
options.setTimeOutInMilliSeconds(timeOutInMilliSeconds);
...
```

If you want more information check: http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/docs/http-transport.html

Also:

http://wso2.org/library/209

http://singztechmusings.wordpress.com/2011/05/07/how-to-configure-timeout-duration-at-client-side-for-axis2-web-services/

If you're using ServiceClient check this thread please: [Axis2 ServiceClient options ignore timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13522686/axis2-serviceclient-options-ignore-timeout)

Please let me know if it worked ;)

Comment: We are using ServiceClient way instead of stub way to call remote service. I don't know if there is a way to get hold of stub from PortType.

Comment: I've updated my answer to point to a solution in another StackOverflow thread. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for reply, i thought i have serviceClient, however when i went back to my genearated websphere code, all i have is: class extending javax.xml.ws.Service   and porttype, and i could not figure out how to set option on either one of two.

Answer (score 0):

You should set JVM properties mentioned in following link -

https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/rwbs_jaxwstimeouts.html

```
bindingProvider.getRequestContext().put(com.ibm.wsspi.webservices.Constants.CONNECTION_TIMEOUT_PROPERTY, timeout);
bindingProvider.getRequestContext().put(com.ibm.wsspi.webservices.Constants.RESPONSE_TIMEOUT_PROPERTY, timeout);
```

Set timeout in seconds as String.